# Can I change my signature in the new passport?

Tags: passports, australian-citizens

I signed my passport when I was 10 years old, when I applied for it the first time. I am but 20 now. It is almost time to renew it. The signature that I gave for the first time is very... childish (and cute :)). Is it possible to change it during the renewal? Say, if I couldn't, will I be able to use a new one in the country that I travel to (filling out official documents and such)? Will they check every signature that I put with the one in my passport?

Comment: what country's passport is this?

Comment: @KateGregory Australia

Comment: I'm not sure about Australia, but the signature in my US passport (about 8 years old now) looks nothing like what I use day-to-day.  And it's certainly different form the signature I had in my previous passport.

Comment: @AleksG That's a relief!

Comment: I've never had anyone even check my passport signature until last week when I paid with a credit card (which I refuse to sign), and my passport was my nearest ID to verify my signature on the receipt. So I don't think the signature on your passport means very much anyway.

Comment: Aren't your passports electronic/digital? They still need signatures on the identification page?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid The signatures are not directly written on the passport, but scanned and printed under a laminated covering.

Comment: Interesting, because on my MRP (but not biometric) passport, there is no signature required. Although one is taken during the application and on receipt, its nowhere to be found on the identification page.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I have a biometric passport with a laminated ID page… and I had to sign it on the next page.

Answer (score 9):

Signing a passport is a requirement for each new passport.  As much as anything else your signature acknowledges that you have read its terms and conditions, and that you took possession of it.

There is no requirement that signatures remain consistent throughout a person's life time.  In your specific case, there would be thousands of applicants in a similar situation.  Not just children, but older folks also whose signature changes.  The examiner who processes your application will have seen the same situation countless times.

Comment: (+1) In my country the signature on national ID cards (not sure about passports anymore but I think it's the same) is taken from the application, digitalized and printed on the card itself. So it's not meant as an acknowledgment that you took possession of it. You have to sign a separate form for that.

Comment: Various countries do it different ways, some digitize and print, some have you sign the passport and actually my daughter's passport has her thumb print.

Comment: @Tom, my young son has three passports and his signature is totally different in all of them. From a scrawl to his attempt at script.

Comment: @Relaxed, which country?

Comment: @Gayot - your son has my daughter beat, she has only 2 passports.

Comment: I just checked my passport, I did in fact sign it directly, it's only the (plastic) ID card which has a digitized signature (not sure if they keep it on file, incidentally).

Comment: @Relaxed, passports invariably require a wet signature. ID's and driving permits vary; and the UK keeps the driving permit signature for 12 years after the license expires.