# Biometric Signature not match with passport signature

Tags: visas, uk

I make a mistake in biometric process. I did my bank account signature in biometric screening which is different from passport signature. Otherwise I did all documentation and finger scanning. Does it effect on my Visa processing does it cause the rejection of my UK Visa in the future? Please help me

Comment: No I am from India, I did whole thing right. But in biometric process I did my bank signature which is different from my passport signature. Otherwise I did whole thing like finger scanning and retina scanning.

Comment: AFAIK other than size (they usually have to fit in a reserved area) there are no actual requirements for signatures, not even that you use and  can consistently sign the same one ... So nothing to worry about. -  See also: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/95227/ https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/37200/